# How to build OpenJDK Shark against llvm 3.0?

Tags: llvm, java, shark-compiler

Recently I learned that there's an openjdk shark project, which uses llvm to make hotspot vm more portable. Since I used to work on jdk and is interested in llvm right now, this is a match made in heaven. So first thing first, how to build openjdk shark against llvm 3.0? To be more specific, which repository in http://hg.openjdk.java.net/ should I begin with? jdk7u, jdk7u2, jdk8, or icedtea?

I prefer latest update release of jdk7 if possible. And I intend to build that in a mac os x.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I recommend asking on the mailing list (distro-pkg-dev@openjdk.java.net).  They're quite helpful.

Comment: That sounds like a good place to start, too. Will do. Thanks, @MatthewFlaschen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some progress. Here's what I did:

- started with [this repository](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u-osx/)
- applied llvm 3.0 patch mentioned [here](http://labb.zafena.se/?p=459)
- and bunch of other make file hacks

But there is a *road blocker*. To support [JSR 292](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=292), a.k.a invoke dynamic, something called Richochet frames has been introduced into Hotspot JVM, which unfortunately hasn't been implemented in zero yet. So the building fails not only on Mac OS X but also on other platforms.

The good news is Chris Phillips from Redhat is working on it. I also learned that the most relevant mailing lists are mlvm-dev and zero-dev at openjdk.java.net, in case someone is interested in the same topic too.